# BigQuery Transfer for DoubleClick Search Reports in to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to transfer data from DoubleClick Search Reports in to BigQuery.  I'm facing an error while doing this as shown in the below:

> [Error]:
>   {Error in creating a new transfer. Please ensure the OAuth popup was not blocked and you have the BigQuery Admin role.: User does not have sufficient permission: bigquery.transfers.update is required on project XX-XXXXX-XXXXX523}

I'm the BigQuery admin(Technical Team) and the account I'm logging in for DoubleClick reports extraction belongs to another person account(Management Team), who is not a BigQuery admin.

My queries here are as follows:

1. Is it possible to directly transfer data from DoubleClick Search Reports in to BigQuery?
2. The error mentioned above we're facing is it because the account we are using for logging in for DoubleClick reports for extraction is not a BigQuery admin?
3. If it is possible to directly transfer data from DoubleClick Search Reports in to BigQuery and the steps we're following is wrong, could you help us out with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the Transfer using the BigQuery web UI, perhaps you just need to allow pop-ups from bigquery.cloud.google.com (as the error message indicates), so the UI can prompt you to review the permissions and allow the action.

About your questions:

1. According to [BigQuery Transfer Service documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-service-overview#supported_data_sources), it is not. However, if you are seeing the option in your BigQuery UI it may be available for your project (happens, for example, with some Alpha releases, where only a limited number of customers who previously requested access can make use of new features).
2. Usually, for BigQuery transfers, the user that is creating the transfer should have Admin access to the datasource, in this case DoubleClick Search and the “bigquery.transfers.update” permission in BigQuery (which is included in the BQ Admin role).
3. It is unclear to me what steps you are following. If you could describe them or add some screenshots, perhaps I can assist you further.